# How jQuery can prevent reopening a new window?

Tags: jquery, window.open

I have the code below to open a new window whenever user presses F2 key.

```
$(document).bind('keyup', function(e){
    if(e.which==113) {
        window.open('newPage.htm','_blank','','false');
    }
});
```

Now, I want to prevent user to open a new window while the previous one is still opened. How can I dot it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var opened = null;
$(document).bind('keyup', function(e){
    if (e.which == 113 && (!opened || !opened.window))
        opened = window.open('newPage.htm','_blank','','false');
​});​
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this ..

```
    var windowOpened=false;

    $(document).bind('keyup', function(e){
        if(e.which==113 && !windowOpened) {
            window.open('newPage.htm','_blank','','false');
            windowOpened=true;
        }
    });




   In the newPage.htm add code to make windowOpened=false when u close that window.


< html> 
< head>
< title>newPage.htm< /title>
<script>
function setFalse()
{
  opener.windowOpened = false;
  self.close();
  return false;
}
</script>
< /head>
< body onbeforeunload="setFalse()">
< /body> 
< /html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your window a name like

```
var mywindow = window.open("foo.html","windowName");
```

Then you can check if window is closed by doing

```
if (mywindow.closed) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

When the windows is closed, what happens with window.document ? Does it become null , maybe you can check it by null.

```
var popupWindow;

$(document).bind('keyup', function(e){
    if(e.which==113 && (!popupWindow || !popupWindow.document)) {
        popupWindow = window.open('newPage.htm','_blank','','false');
    }
});
```