# how to prevent reopening new window using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, window.open

I've recently posted a new question in [How jQuery can prevent reopening a new window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9358354/jquery-prevent-reopen-a-new-window/9358462). At that post, I mentioned to my need for something on **F2** key.
Now I want to ask another question similar to the question above; This time for clicking on a link.
I have a link that opens a new window using `window.open`. I want to prevent user to reopening new window when he clicks on the list if the previous window is still opened.

What is your suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do:

```
var childWin;
    function winOpen(url)
    {
       //check if child window is already open
       if (childWin &! childWin.closed && childWin.focus){
           childWin.focus();
       } else {
          childWin = window.open(url,'','width=800,height=600');
      }
    }
```

Did you mean something like this

Comment: No new window is coming. Even if we click the link for first time, it is opening in the same window.

Answer (score 6):

You can try this, it will help you to open and observe multiple windows, check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/sLCxe/)

**Javascript**

```
var windows = {};
$('a').click(function(e){
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    var name = $(this).attr('id');
    if(windows.hasOwnProperty(name) && !windows[name].closed ) 
    {
       windows[name].focus();   
    }
    else  
    {
       windows[name]=window.open (url,name,"status=1,width=300,height=300");
    }    
});
```

**Your Links**

```
<a href="http://google.com" id="google">Google</a>
<a href="http://yahoo.com" id="yahoo">Yahoo</a>​
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/PR9FE/)