# Focus already opened window

Tags: javascript, html, servlets

I have two HTML pages. The first contains a link; `onclick` of this, the 2nd page is opened. When user tries to click the link again I check if the 2nd page is opened or not; if it is opened I focus, otherwise I open the page. This worked smoothly in both IE and Chrome.
I changed the 2nd page a little bit, having an `onload` fucntion which invokes a servlet and reloads the page with the servlet's content.
The problem is, the 2nd page is focusing in google chrome while it is not focusing in 
IE after changing?

JS on first page:

```
var childWindow = null;
var yourLink = '/FirstJSPOne/child.html';  

function doIt() {
if (!childWindow) {
        childWindow = window.open(yourLink,'childWindow',
'toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,copyhistory=no');

    } else {
        try {

            childWindow.focus();
        } catch (e) {
            childWindow = window.open(yourLink,'childWindow',
'toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,copyhistory=no');
        }
    }
}
```

JS on 2<sup>nd</sup> page:

```
function submitForm(){
var formName =  document.forms[0];
formName.submit();
}
```

HTML on 2<sup>nd</sup> page:

```
<body onload="submitForm()">
<form id="child" action="SelectBeer.do" method="post">
</form>
```

Comment: [Could be helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9390504/how-to-prevent-reopening-new-window-using-jquery/9391600#9391600).

Comment: How about changing the form's `id` to something other than `child`?

Comment: @ThatWeirdo it did not work

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha i need to use javascript ,no jquery.

Comment: @Seven_7, You get the idea from it and use `vanilla JS`.